# Show Content after clicking 'Show More'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently building a functionality where it display all of the content after clicking `Show More` button. I've managed to make one after checking some of the tutorials but instead of having to click each `Show More` button, it will show all of the hidden content.

Initially it will show the first heading and first list and the rest will be hidden both headings and lists until clicking the `Show More` button

https://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/z0qvv7tk/4/

```
<h3>List 1</h3>
<ul class="expandible">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>

<h3>List 2</h3>
<ul class="expandible">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$('ul.expandible').each(function(){
    var $ul = $(this),
        $lis = $ul.find('li:gt(4)'),
        isExpanded = $ul.hasClass('expanded');
    $lis[isExpanded ? 'show' : 'hide']();

    if($lis.length > 0){
        $ul
            .append($('<li class="expand"><span>' + (isExpanded ? 'Show Less' : 'Show More') + '</span></li>')
            .click(function(event){
                var isExpanded = $ul.hasClass('expanded');
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).text(isExpanded ? 'More' : 'Less');
                $ul.toggleClass('expanded');
                $lis.toggle();
            }));
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want a universal "show more" button that will work across all lists?

Comment: @Terry yes, instead of clicking each `Show More` Button

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this? 
Add 2 links to show and collapse all.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="show-all">show all</a>
<a href="#" class="close-all">collapse all</a>
```

JS

```
$(".show-all").click(function(e) {
  $("ul li").show();
  $(".expand").text("Show Less");
  e.preventDefault();
});

$(".close-all").click(function(e) {
  $("ul").find('li:gt(2)').hide();
  $(".expand")
    .show()
    .text("Show More");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/z0qvv7tk/7/)